# iOS Crashlogs: What is the 'Non UI' task role?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash, crash-reports

I have some trouble understanding a specific entry in iOS crashlogs.
While analyzing some crashlogs for my app from the app store, I often come across this line:

```
Role:                Non UI
```

For other logs I see "foreground" or something more understandable as the role. My first thought was that it has something todo with background execution or the app woke up due to backgroundFetch or something similar. But then I would expect "background" or something more applicable as the role.

When looking it up in https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/osfmk/mach/task_policy.h it won't give me any other information else than there would be a 'background' value for the role.

Does anyone know what the role 'Non UI' means? Is the app visible to the user? Does in run in the background (due to backgroundFetch or CoreLocation Updates)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just asked a related question an hour back - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870766/print-background-or-main-thread-operation